# Is macbook pro 2019 worth it in 2022?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bootcamp

I'm writing to ask for advice: I have to buy a new laptop and I was thinking of buying an apple one, but for school reasons I need windows (uwp and winforms development), so I was considering a  2019 macbook pro i7 16".
It would be worth it especially from the point of view of the duration of the new computer (I hope at least 5 years)?
Thanks to anyone that will help me.

Comment: See https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2022/07/some-macs-are-getting-fewer-updates-than-they-used-to-heres-why-its-a-problem/ for the average support length of macOS on Macs. Don't skimp on the SSD, development eat storage for breakfast.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-10-home-and-pro), the retirement date for Windows 10 is Oct 14, 2025. This is less than 5 years away. A 2019 MacBook Pro i7 16" does not officially support Windows 11.

Even though this Mac lacks a Trusted Platform Module (TPM), most likely Windows 11 can still be installed on this Mac model. However, the best way to avoid unforeseen problems would be to purchase a computer which is full Windows 11 compatible.